# How to update plot in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create an interactive app in Shiny. It is looks like below:

[image]

**summary :** user adds a .csv file with HOUR and DEMAND as two fields. Further user is asked to  select a radio button (it changes as per selection in dropdown menu). As it can be seen right now the selection is '500' which is reflected in the graph (as green).

**what i am not able to do :** when the user makes another selection (say '250') i want to show the addition of 500 + 250 in the graph.

**Issue:** i need to somehow update the reactive expression *lastgang()*  in *eventReactive* function  which i believe is not possible. Is there some other way to do this. I am new to Rshiny. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Below is code in server.R and ui.R files.

**server.R**

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(shiny)


  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    lastgang <- reactive({

      if(is.null(input$file)){return()} 
      data = read.table(file=input$file$datapath, header =TRUE, sep=",")
      data$source = rep(0, nrow(data))
      data
    })


    db_source =read.table(file="example.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    choice = as.character(db_source$Source.Typ)

    choose1 = reactive({

      if (is.null(input$engine)){return()} 

      subcat= character(0)

      for (i in 1:nrow(db_source)){
        if  (input$engine == as.character(db_source$Source.Typ[i]))
        {
          #count = count +1
          #subcat = c(subcat, paste(as.character(db_source$Produkt[i]),"(",as.character(db_source$kW.max[i]), "kW", ")"))
          subcat = c(subcat, db_source$kW.max[i])
        }
      }
      subcat

    })


    output$radio = renderUI({radioButtons("cp", "Select Capacity (kW)",  choices = choose1()) })


    db = eventReactive(input$update,
                       {
                         intermediate = rep(0, nrow(lastgang()))

                         temp = lastgang()
                         for ( i in 1:nrow(temp)){
                           if (temp$Demand[i] > as.numeric(input$cp) )
                           {
                             intermediate[i] =  as.numeric(input$cp)
                           }
                           else {

                             intermediate[i] = temp$Demand[i] 
                           }
                         }

                         temp$source = temp$source + intermediate
                         temp

                       })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 

      ggplot(db(), aes(x = Hour )) + 
        labs(title = "Supply and Demand")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=2))+
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=Demand), fill="red") + 
        geom_line(aes(y=Demand, colour="Demand")) + 
        geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=source), fill="green") + 
        geom_line(aes(y=source, colour="Supply") )+
        scale_colour_manual(name='', values=c("Demand"="red", "Supply"="green"))
    })


  })
```

**ui.R**

```
  library(shiny)

  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Source Design"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

                  fileInput("file", label = h4("Select *.csv file")),

                  br(),
                   selectInput("engine", "Select the Source", choices = choice),
                   br(),
                   uiOutput('radio'),

                  actionButton("update", "Submit")

                   ),

      mainPanel(

        plotOutput('plot'),

      )
    )

  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstand things here but based on

> when the user makes another selection (say '250') i want to show the addition of 500 + 250 in the graph.

I am thinking that radio options might not be the best alternative in your case.

The idea with radio options is that only one alternative is selectable. Every time the user selects an option, something happens. If you were to store the old value somehow you would then stack (in this case "add")  values every time the user interacts with the radio options.

Maybe you would rather want a slider instead? or A text input with suggestions?

Comment: the values in radio button have to be these discreet values only. it is a specification of the application underneath. So i could not allow user to select anything between them.